# SQLite query accepts some values with apostrophes but not others

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm pulling the title of books from an SQLite database. I've used a parameter injection to try to pull titles with apostrophes in them, but some work and some crash the app.

The title that works is *The Adventure of the Engineer's Thumb* but *The Adventure of the Stockbroker's Clerk* and *The Adventure of the "Gloria Scott"* both throw up errors. I can't see a pattern here...

Snippet from DatabaseHelper:

```
public String getStoryBody(String story) {

   String storyBody = "";

   // Select all query
   String selectQuery = "SELECT body FROM " + BOOKS + " WHERE title = ?";

   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {story});

   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
           storyBody = cursor.getString(0);
       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }

   return storyBody;
}
```

Snippet from StoryBodyActivity:

```
storyBodyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story_body_text_view);
storyBodyScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.story_body_scroll_view);

DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

String storyBody = db.getStoryBody(story);

Log.i("story", storyBody);

storyBodyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(storyBody));
```

**EDIT**

The error generated is a null pointer exception on the `Log.i("story", storyBody);` line:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

**EDIT 2**

My database structure is:

Books

- id
- title
- author_id
- collection
- body

Comment: Post the errors! Also dont use rawQuery for just a select

Comment: What is in BOOKS variable?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed `private static final String BOOKS = "books";`

Comment: what is the name of the column of zero index

Comment: @AbdulWaheed see my second edit

Comment: that means you are trying to get data from body column..is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 1):

Apostrophes can look the same to you but actually be different characters. In this specific case if you copy the one from the engineer's thumb and use that one to replace all other quotes in the titles it will work.

What happens:
The one that does not work is straighter if you look closely. It makes your code incomplete as everything that happens after it will be seen as code, then when the actual "text ending" happens it will now read the code after that as text.
This problem should be addressed when importing the records into the database!

Comment: Hey, I tried this but it didn't work for some reason.